SLD - Generate a PointSybolizer's geometry based on properties
I have this kind of data template that represent an hiking circuit :
"name","parking_location_x","parking_location_y","departure_geom_x","departure_geom_y","difficulty","duration","ascent","descent","max_elevation","min_elevation","geom"    
"Agrain de Folie","3.6690921","44.9152789","3.669311968764941","44.915564167566664",3,"2.5",844,-844,1241,651,<geom_data>

And I would like to symbolize :

The linestring that represents the circuit (geom)
A point for the parking location (parking_location_x,parking_location_y)
A point for the departure (departure_geom_x,departure_geom_y)

Here is the SLD I have currently try :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name/>
    <UserStyle>
      <Name/>
      <Title/>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <Name>Circuit «Promenade et Randonnée»</Name>
          <LineSymbolizer>
            <Stroke>
              <CssParameter name="stroke">#8c7c17</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-width">2</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-dasharray">4</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-dashoffset">2</CssParameter>
            </Stroke>
          </LineSymbolizer>
          <TextSymbolizer>
            <Font>
              <CssParameter name="font-size">12</CssParameter>
            </Font>
          </TextSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
        <Rule>
          <Name>Parking</Name>
          <Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <And>
              <Not>
                <PropertyIsNull>
                  <PropertyName>parking_location_x</PropertyName>
                </PropertyIsNull>
              </Not>
              <Not>
                <PropertyIsNull>
                  <PropertyName>parking_location_y</PropertyName>
                </PropertyIsNull>
              </Not>
            </And>
          </Filter>
          <PointSymbolizer>
            <Geometry>
                <ogc:Function name="geomFromWKT">
                    <ogc:Function name="Concatenate">
                        <ogc:Literal>POINT(</ogc:Literal>
                        <ogc:PropertyName>parking_location_x</ogc:PropertyName>
                        <ogc:Literal><![CDATA[ ]]></ogc:Literal>
                        <ogc:PropertyName>parking_location_y</ogc:PropertyName>
                        <ogc:Literal>)</ogc:Literal>
                    </ogc:Function>
                </ogc:Function>
            </Geometry>
            <Graphic>
              <Mark>
                <WellKnownName>square</WellKnownName>
                <Fill>
                  <CssParameter name="fill">#ff0000</CssParameter>
                </Fill>
              </Mark>
              <Size>6</Size>
            </Graphic>
          </PointSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
        <Rule>
          <Name>Départ</Name>
          <Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <And>
              <Not>
                <PropertyIsNull>
                  <PropertyName>departure_geom_x</PropertyName>
                </PropertyIsNull>
              </Not>
              <Not>
                <PropertyIsNull>
                  <PropertyName>departure_geom_y</PropertyName>
                </PropertyIsNull>
              </Not>
            </And>
          </Filter>
          <PointSymbolizer>
            <Geometry>
                <ogc:Function name="geomFromWKT">
                    <ogc:Function name="Concatenate">
                        <ogc:Literal>POINT(</ogc:Literal>
                        <ogc:PropertyName>departure_geom_x</ogc:PropertyName>
                        <ogc:Literal><![CDATA[ ]]></ogc:Literal>
                        <ogc:PropertyName>departure_geom_y</ogc:PropertyName>
                        <ogc:Literal>)</ogc:Literal>
                    </ogc:Function>
                </ogc:Function>
            </Geometry>
            <Graphic>
              <Mark>
                <WellKnownName>square</WellKnownName>
                <Fill>
                  <CssParameter name="fill">#00ff00</CssParameter>
                </Fill>
              </Mark>
              <Size>6</Size>
            </Graphic>
          </PointSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>

But when rendered, the points symbolizers looks like they have wrong EPSG :

I use GeoServer (2.25.2) for rendering.
The layer is projected in EPSG:4326
The viewer (Mapstore2) request the data in EPSG:3857
Example request :

https:///geoserver/ows?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fvnd.jpeg-png&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=geotrek%3Acircuits_pr&STYLES=&SRS=EPSG%3A3857&CRS=EPSG%3A3857&TILED=false&WIDTH=1920&HEIGHT=804&BBOX=-78503690.40611425%2C-11746864.975315683%2C-3363034.120654583%2C19718284.844220553

Why does the points symbolizer look like they are out of bounds?

I don't think there is any way to set the SRS when generating a point from text inside a SLD file. Have you tried just storing the locations in the data as geometries?

This is what I finally did. Effectively, the coordinates provided to geomFromWKT are not reprojected to the requested SRS. Thanks for the suggestion.
